# QGIS3: Report for just one Feature

Tags: qgis-3, reports

I made a report that shows the data of a feature and its children. But I want to generate just one by one, not the whole set of features.

There's a way to set the feature for the report as it could be done for the atlas?

This is the way that the report is organised, for each feature on **v_fxcc_ficha**
Y have several on **inmuebles:**

[image]

Also name the report depending on the values of the feature's iD

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same thing, and I can only find a filter if I add an attribute table to the report, nothing allowing me to report on only selected data...